# Resizing a table

Tags: css, html, html-table, width

I have a table on a HTML page but I have other tables on other pages with width and height set to auto.

I would like to change only this table to a set width and height but cant find how to.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: here is what you're searching for ? http://jsfiddle.net/N7bk2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you copied and pasted the other tables on the other pages? So the first line on those tables would look like this:

```
<table width="auto" height="auto">
...
</table>
```

Simply add the width and height amounts as required instead of the word "auto" for both, like this:

```
<table width="300" height="300">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the table a unique id, then in your css refer to that id.

Comment: Then you need to post your code so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can control width of table using : `table-layout:fixed;` .

to hide overflow horizontally, you need then to set `overflow:hidden;` to `td`s and `th`s.
You cannot control `max-height`, table will grow as much inside content needs space.